# collada2gltf converter can't produce *.json file

Tags: collada, gltf

I am reading a book: *Programming 3D Applications with HTML5 and WebG* , it involve a Vizi framework.

All the examples load the `*.json` file instead of `*.gltf` file. Why?

When I load `*.gltf`, it doesn't load any result, and the collada2gltf converters only produce `*.gltf`, `*.bin`, `*.glsl` files and so on.

What should I do?

Comment: Can you please try and format your question better? it's hard to read when everything is a single block of text.

Also, some information is missing. maybe include the example?

Answer (score 1):

`.gltf` is a JSON file. Try to open it with a text editor and see for youself. `.bin` and `.glsl` files are just additional resources, linked from `.gltf` file. Those are geometry buffers and shaders respectively. So to make it work you should make sure that all the files produced with the converter are also available to a web browser you running your code in.

Also you can try to add `-e` CLI flag to `collada2gltf` and it'll embed all the resources into result `.gltf` file.

Comment: I know *.gltf file is json format file,but how to get the extention-name *.json file, instead of *.gltf.what should I do ?

Comment: In the Programming 3D Applications with HTML5 and WebG, all examples files are *.json, *.bin, *.glsl and so on. when I use collada2gltf tool, produce *.gltf, *.bin, *.glsl and so on, then rename *.glsl to *.json, and load it by the example program of the book, but it failed! why?

Comment: That's because [Vizi doesn't use glTF](https://github.com/tparisi/Vizi/blob/master/engine/src/loaders/loader.js#L44), it uses Three.js JSON. However, there is, for example, [a Blender exporter](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/utils/exporters/blender).

Comment: how to get the *.json, *.bin, *.glsl files at the same time? Can you give me a detailed procedure? for example, how to get the *.json file, how to get *.bin file, how to get *.glsl file?  I will appreciate!

Comment: In the Programming 3D Applications with HTML5 and WebG, it always includes three files:*.dae file, *.json file, *.bin file  and so on in the models directory. How I get that?

Comment: Why are you so keen on including all files? I've gave you links to a way to convert COLLADA to Three.js JSON (via Blender).

Comment: thank you very much, but most examples in the book, every directory includes *.json, *.bin, *.dae, *.glsl files. now I need know how to generate them. for example, I can get the *.json file, but how to get the *.bin file? I need a detailed procedure!

Comment: At the same time, I need the most important three files, including *.json, *.bin, *.dae files in my application. So I am so keen on including all files.